# Copying Firmware to 3560X Switch Ends SSH Session & Erases File

Tags: networking, cisco, firmware, tftp

I am simply trying to copy a new firmware file to a 3560X switch by connecting via SSH and copying it from a tftp server to the flash memory.  The process commences, the transfer gets all the way to the end but when it complete, it boots me out of my SSH session and when I log back in, the firmware file is nowhere to be found.  I opened a second SSH session and watched the flash and it does build the file as it's uploading, but it disappears when it's complete.  I don't get a screen showing that it attempted to verify the file, it seems to happen immediately when the transfer is complete.  I'm also logged in as a user with root privileges.  There were no log entries out of the ordinary during this time.

I've already done this to over 100 other switches, so I know the process like the back of my hand.  I don't know why this one switch is having issues.  I did some googling but either didn't know what to search for or no one else has posted about this issue.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of IOS?, Do you have enough room in flash?

Comment: Try a different IOS file. Perhaps that one is corrupt.

Comment: Which command set are you using to load the switch - tar or copy?  Is the switch bouncing when the copy is complete or are there any tracebacks in the logs?

Comment: If the flash isn't full which would be my thought, I'd recommend to call TAC

Comment: Since you've done this several times successfully, I'm going to assume that you've already checked that there's enough flash memory available. Even then, filling up the flash should not disconnect you from SSH. I would say it's a bug as well or a faulty unit.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I ended up circumvented this somehow but I don't remember exactly how.  It might have been by erasing the flash and uploading the file then or by copying it from another switch with that firmware.  I apologize for not following up with my solution.

Comment: Not an answer. Leaving this comment till I'm out of flagban.